# if G is supersoluble group then $[G,G]$ is nilpotent

Tags: group-theory

Let G infinite group.

if G is  supersoluble group then $[G,G]$ is nilpotent.

a group G is called supersolvable (or supersoluble) if it has an invariant normal series 
whose factors are all cyclic. Since a normal series has finite length by definition.

Comment: Why are assuming that $G$ is infinite? It is unnecessary.

Comment: yes of course ,just because i always work with infinite group

Answer (score 1):

This is Theorem $4.20$ in Keith Conrad's notes [Subgroup Series II](http://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB8QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.uconn.edu%2F~kconrad%2Fblurbs%2Fgrouptheory%2Fsubgpseries2.pdf&ei=DNntVOT5OcGyU72TgugK&usg=AFQjCNG8yxst18puzgshHl8-cdQ0Vn-izA&bvm=bv.86956481,d.d24), where a detailed proof is given.

*Rekark*: One has to be careful not to use a wrong argument, which might come to mind: since a supersolvable group is clearly solvable, it should have nilpotent commutator subgroup. This is false, with counterexample $G=S_4$, see 
[If a finite group $G$ is solvable, is $[G,G]$ nilpotent?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/272849/if-a-finite-group-g-is-solvable-is-g-g-nilpotent)